# C++ password generator with WinAPI clipboard function

Tags: c++, winapi

I made a simple password generator with a *copy-to-clipboard* functionality implemented via WinAPI calls. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <Windows.h>

void copytoclipboard(const std::string& s){
    HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, s.size() + 1);
    memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), s.c_str(), s.size() + 1);
    GlobalUnlock(hMem);
    OpenClipboard(0);
    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
    CloseClipboard();
}
int main(){
    std::string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789%^&$+-_!@#%?";
    std::string pw = "";
    const int pass_length = 12;
    const int from = 0;
    const int to = chars.size();
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int>  distr(from, to);
    auto rng = std::default_random_engine{};
    std::shuffle(chars.begin(), chars.end(), rng);
    for (int i = 0; i < pass_length; ++i){
        pw.push_back(chars[distr(g)]);
    }
    copytoclipboard(pw);
}
```

What can be improved and are there any pitfalls with the above approach such as the lack of `GlobalFree(hMem);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Out Of Bounds Problem**

```
const int to = chars.size();
...
std::uniform_int_distribution<int>  distr(from, to);
```

[uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) - *Produces random integer values i, uniformly distributed on the closed interval [a, b]*

So if chars were "ABC", size is 3, and the range of values returned would be [0,3]
 = 0,1,2 and 3. 3 is an invalid index. Therefore 'to' should be chars.size() - 1.

**Error Checking**

You should check the return values on system functions like [OpenClipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649048(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
if (!OpenClipboard())
{
    auto lastError = GetLastError();
    // get error message, throw exception?
}
```

**GlobalFree**

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649051(v=vs.85).aspx) - *If SetClipboardData succeeds, the system owns the object identified by the hMem parameter. The application may not write to **or free the data** once ownership has been transferred to the system*

So it looks like a GlobalFree call is not needed. You should free it though if SetClipboardData (or any of the other system calls) fails.